# Convert event delegate from C# to VB.NET

Tags: delegates, action, c#-to-vb.net

Tried to convert this code to VB.NET using the various online converters but none worked (got an error on the event handler declaration). I'm using VS 2012 and .Net 4.5. Any ideas?

```
readonly Action<IDialogManager, Action<bool>> closeCheck;

public void Execute(ActionExecutionContext context) {
        closeCheck(Shell.Dialogs, result => Completed(this, new ResultCompletionEventArgs { WasCancelled = !result }));
    }

public event EventHandler<ResultCompletionEventArgs> Completed = delegate { };
```

Answer (score 0):

I created dummy types in LinqPad and got this:

```
ReadOnly closeCheck As Action(Of IDialogManager, Action(Of Boolean))

Public Sub Execute(ByVal Context As ActionExecutionContext)
    closeCheck(Shell.Dialogs, Sub(Result) RaiseEvent Completed(Me, New ResultCompletionEventArgs With { .WasCancelled = Not Result }))
End Sub

Public Event Completed As EventHandler(Of ResultCompletionEventArgs)
```